MongoDB SSL HandShake Fail
Every time that i need to make a quary this error apears. The IP that's added on MondoDB Network Access is 0.0.0.0/0, i already tried to change the user, password, login and cluster. But it dosen't solve the problem. And at the same time that the error heppend at my machine in other machines it donsn't happend and when it happens in another machine it dosen't happen at mine.
This is my code:
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import logging
import os

class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        load_dotenv()

        DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
        DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
        DB_CLUSTER = os.getenv('DB_CLUSTER')
        
        try:
            connection_string = f"mongodb+srv://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net/"

            self.client = MongoClient(connection_string)
            self.db = self.client["IPs"]
            self.info = self.db["info"]

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to connect to MongoDB: {e}")
            
    
    def getIPs(self):
        info = list(self.info.find({}))
        print(info)
        
        self.client.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = Database()
    db.getIPs()

The error:
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-00.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-02.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-01.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6636c72ea902572c1d2b9261, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-00.gcolnp2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-00.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-01.gcolnp2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-01.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-02.gcolnp2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-ccnc26s-shard-00-02.gcolnp2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1006) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>


Does this answer your question? How to connect to mi MongoDB compass?

My IP is already added ate the MondoDB Network Access.

This is a TLS alert send by the server to the client. So you need to check logs at the server end.
